# Unresolved reference on pointerInput and detectTransformGestures

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here's the error log:
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun Modifier.pointerInput(key1: Any?, key2: Any?, block: suspend PointerInputScope.() -> Unit): Modifier defined in androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer
public fun Modifier.pointerInput(key1: Any?, block: suspend PointerInputScope.() -> Unit): Modifier defined in androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer
public fun Modifier.pointerInput(vararg keys: Any?, block: suspend PointerInputScope.() -> Unit): Modifier defined in androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer
public fun Modifier.pointerInput(block: suspend PointerInputScope.() -> Unit): Modifier defined in androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer. Line 80

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectTransformGestures(panZoomLock: Boolean = ..., onGesture: (centroid: Offset, pan: Offset, zoom: Float, rotation: Float) -> Unit): Unit defined in androidx.compose.foundation.gestures. Line 81

I'm trying to make a simple mobile app that let you draw on your phone. Sort of Paint app on PC. I'm using jetpack compose for it. Using kotlin.

Here is the code for the DrawingArea:

```
// Drawing
            val density = LocalDensity.current.density

            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { _, pan, _, _ ->
                        if (pan != Offset(0f, 0f)) {
                            val scaledPan = pan * density
                            points = points + Offset(scaledPan.x, scaledPan.y)
                        }
                    }
                }

                val paint = Paint().apply {
                    color = Color.Black
                    strokeWidth = 5f
                    style = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.PaintingStyle.Stroke
                }
```

i've also imported

```
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
```

I've also modified the needed dependencies on build.gradle.kts for the compose

I've asked my colleague and chatGPT for the solution, but still on dead end. Would really appreciate the help :D (i'm new to android studio, please explain it carefully :)

Comment: You are trying to call `pointerInput` inside `Canvas`. That's not right, it's a `Modifier` extension function.

Comment: (by the way, I tried to ask ChatGPT about this just as an exercise and you're right: It gets this completely wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `pointerInput` as a `Modifier` extension function, instead of inside `Canvas`:

```
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                         detectTransformGestures { _, pan, _, _ ->
                             if (pan != Offset(0f, 0f)) {
                                 val scaledPan = pan * density
                                 points = points + Offset(scaledPan.x, scaledPan.y)
                             }
                         }
                     }

            ) {
                // ... content
            }
```

Comment: It solved :D, thanks a bunch man. Much appreciated. I'm new to android studio and still learning kotlin.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you, please upvote and/or accept it.